# Wrong json data sending to post request

Tags: xamarin.android

hello i send request to server and i want to deserialize json string using newtonsoft

I want to send data like this

```
    {

    "Id": 1,
    "PROF_EMAILD": "aaaa@gmail.com",
    "MAILID": "bbb@gmail.com",
    "NAME": "aaa"
}
```

I have implemented the some code for this.code looks like this

```
 protected override string RunInBackground(params string[] @params)
    {
        string sUrl = "http://52.163.215.46:4444/api/FBLogins";
        string sContentType = "application/json"; // or application/xml
        try
        {
            JObject oJsonObject = new JObject();
            oJsonObject.Add("Id", 22);
            oJsonObject.Add("PROF_EMAILD", "aaa@gmail.com");

            oJsonObject.Add("MAILID", "aa@gmail.com");

            oJsonObject.Add("NAME", "aaa");


            HttpClient oHttpClient = new HttpClient();
            var oTaskPostAsync = oHttpClient.PostAsync(sUrl, new StringContent(oJsonObject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, sContentType));
            oTaskPostAsync.ContinueWith((oHttpResponseMessage) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Abhijit", oHttpResponseMessage.ToString());
            });
        }
        catch (Java.Lang.Exception e)
        {

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {

        }
        return null;

    }
```

But while sending request json look like this

```
    {{

    "Id": 1,
    "PROF_EMAILD": "aaa@gmail.com",
    "MAILID": "aa@gmail.com",
    "NAME": "aaa"
}}//extra bracks
```

and i how to get responce string and how to convert that in json

Answer (score 0):

Can you try without new Sting Like.
var oTaskPostAsync = oHttpClient.PostAsync(sUrl, oJsonObject.ToString());

Thanks

Comment: It gives error cannot convert from string to system.net.http.httpcontent

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach would be to do something similar as the examples on the newtonsoft documentation pages https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm

Create a model of the data to send:

```
public class Users
{
   public int Id {get; set;}
   public string PROF_EMAILD {get; set;}
   public string MAILID{get; set;}
   public string NAME{get; set;}
}
```

Instantiate the class with your data:

```
Users user = new Users();
...ADD DATA TO USERS ...

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    var content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(user));
    content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

    var response = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("http://your-url"), content);

    /* handle response here*/
};
```

Then post the 'output' to the API

Comment: Sir how to make request with that data

Comment: i am getting error                 var oTaskPostAsync = oHttpClient.PostAsync("api/FBLogin", output);

Comment: Ya tried your ans but control doesnt go inside following statement

Comment: oTaskPostAsync.ContinueWith((oHttpResponseMessage) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Abhijit", oHttpResponseMessage.ToString());
            });